# larevl 8 : foreach inside of foreach id is alwys last id pick

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

Overview :

I make a booking system user can carte multiple appointments (based on date unique date) than with that date they can add time for the selected date

Here is my view of that

```html
 <form action="{{ route('user.booking') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             @foreach ($appget as $appdata)
                 <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-header">
                        <b>
                            {{ $appdata->date }}
                        </b>
                        <br>
                            <span class="text-warning">
                                per slot we allow only {{ $appdata->count }} booking
                            </span>
                 </div>
                 {{ $appdata->id }}
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="row">
                        @php
                            $times = DB::table('times')                    ->where('app_id', $appdata->id)->get();
                        @endphp
                        @error('time')
                            <span class="text text-danger">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                        @foreach ($times as $item)
                            @php
                                $blocktime = DB::table('bookings')
                                    ->where('app_id', $appdata->id)
                                    ->where('time', $item->time)
                                    ->where('status', 1)
                                    ->get();                
                                $apoiid = DB::table('appointments')->where('id',$appdata->id)->first();
                                $totlal = $appdata->count;
                            @endphp
                            {{-- @if (count($blocktime) < $totlal) --}}
                            <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                    <input type="radio" name="time" value="{{ $item->time }}">
                                        <span>
                                            {{ $item->time }}
                                        </span>
                                        {{-- <input type="text" name="date" value="{{ $appdata->date }}"> --}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            {{-- @endif --}}
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="{{ $appdata->id }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</form>
```

Explain what I did here :

1st I foreach my appoints then inside of for each I for each time

My front end looks like this:

[image]

you can see

2021-04-22  have 2 times 9.00 Am and 9.30 AM for this app id is 3

2021-04-23 have 2 times 10.00 Am and 10.30 AM for this app id is 4

2021-04-20 have  no time  for this app id is 5

In my form I try to get this id using this:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="{{ $apoiid->id }}">
```

But this value always pass 5 (last appointment id).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

That way you can get them all as an array. You should also edit other inputs.

```
...
@foreach ($appget as $key => $appdata)
...

...
<input type="hidden" name="data[{{$key}}][app_id]" value="{{ $apoiid->id }}">
...
```

Comment: in controller how can i get this name?

Comment: $arr = $request->get('data'); You can use it to get all array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you have all in one form, so you have 3x name="app_id" and the last is always used. I would foreach new form for each, so you get the right data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="{{ $apoiid->id }}">
```